# How do i read uploaded text file contents in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have made upload image UI. I am able to browse and select the text file but how do i read the uploaded text file.

Comment: A similar Question for Vaadin Flow (versions 10+): [*Uploading contents of a text file to a string in memory using the “Upload” widget in Vaadin 14*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58493706/642706)

Answer (score 0):

A uploaded file can either be written to disk on server side or directly processed in the receiving server process.

https://vaadin.com/de/book/-/page/components.upload.html