# Uploading contents of a text file to a string in memory using the "Upload" widget in Vaadin 14

Tags: java, file-upload, upload, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I know Vaadin 14 offers the [*Upload*](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-upload) component for the user to either pick a file(s) to upload or to drag-and-drop file(s).

But I am not sure how to use it. I want the contents of a plain text file on the web browser’s machine to load into memory as a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) or [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) on the server machine.

While the description page for that component has some examples, I could use a complete yet minimal example of loading plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example view in Vaadin 14.1.0.alpha3. I am not an expert on `Upload`, so there may be better approaches, but this seems to be working.

[image: Screenshot of Vaadin "Upload" component in action.]

Notice the [`@Route`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.0.alpha3/com/vaadin/flow/router/Route.html) annotation, and adjust to suit your own app.

The [`Upload`](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-upload) component is a visual widget that appears on your web page, inviting the user to drag-and-drop files(s) or to use a file-picker dialog. We add an anonymous listener object, defined here in lambda syntax, to be invoked when the user does so. A [`FinishedEvent`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.0.alpha3/com/vaadin/flow/component/upload/FinishedEvent.html) object is passed to our listener as our handle for the file(s) being uploaded.

The object receiving the uploaded octets is any implementation of the Vaadin [`Receiver`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.0.alpha3/com/vaadin/flow/component/upload/Receiver.html) interface. To load a single file into memory, use [`MemoryBuffer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.0.alpha3/com/vaadin/flow/component/upload/receivers/MemoryBuffer.html) implementation. By passing a `MemoryBuffer` instance to our `Upload` instance, we are designating a place for the uploaded octets to go as they arrive on the server.

We use an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html) to manage the flow of arriving octets. In this example we read the arriving octets one-by-one. Alternatively, there are ways to read many octets together.

Our `InputStream` reads each octet as an `int` with a value in the range from 0-255 inclusive. A value of `-1` is a signal the stream of inputs has ended. So we collect these `int` values in a `while` loop until a negative one appears.

We use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to [automatically close](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) the `InputStream` that loads bytes from the client to the server.

We collect the arriving octets in a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). The next step is making sense of those collected octets. There is no magic here. You must know the intended content such as [plain text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text) versus formatted text versus [tab-delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) data versus binary data versus document format like [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF). In this example, we expect plain text. And for text we must know the character encoding such as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), or the legacy [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding. In our case, we expect UTF-8 encoding. So we put this together by instantiating a new `String` object, passing to the constructor our collect octets and an enum object signifying our expectation of UTF-8: `new String( bytesReceived.toByteArray() , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 )`.

With our new String in hand, we echo back to the user the contents of the file by instantiating an HTML paragraph.

Here is the entire example class.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Paragraph;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.FinishedEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.Upload;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.receivers.MemoryBuffer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Route ( "upload" )
public class UploadView extends VerticalLayout
{
    // Constructor
    public UploadView ( )
    {
        this.add( new H1( "Upload" ) );
        MemoryBuffer buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
        Upload upload = new Upload( buffer );  // Connect our server-side `Receiver` implementation to the client-side `Upload` widget.
        upload.addFinishedListener(
                ( FinishedEvent finishedEvent ) -> {  // Event fired when user uses the `Upload` widget on the web page.
                    try (  // Autoclosable interface used in try-with-resources syntax.
                           InputStream inputStream = buffer.getInputStream() ;
                    )
                    {
                        // read the contents of the buffer.
                        // https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-array-of-bytes
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytesReceived = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        int content; // Represents each octet arriving on server from client.
                        while ( ( content = inputStream.read() ) != - 1 )  // The arriving octet is returned to us as an `int` in the range 0 to 255. A value of -1 signals end-of-stream. Blocks until data arrives or stream closes.
                        {
                            bytesReceived.write( content );  // Collect the arriving octets into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.
                        }
                        // Parse the collected octets as being text in UTF-8 encoding.
                        String s = new String( bytesReceived.toByteArray() , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );  // You must know the particular  character-encoding used in the file.
                        this.add( new Paragraph( s ) );  // Echo the file contents back to the user.
                        System.out.println( "s = " + s );
                    }
                    catch ( IOException e )
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );
        this.add( upload );  // Make the `Upload` instance named `upload` appear on our Vaadin-produced web page.
    }
}
```

---

We can simplify the code above. Vaadin 14.1 comes bundled with [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) 2.5 library. That library has a convenience method for taking an `InputStream` and producing a `String`. So can turn a chunk of our code above into one-liner. Call static method [`org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)). Pass the input stream, and specify the expected character encoding.

Revised code:

```
package work.basil.example ;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Paragraph;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.FinishedEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.Upload;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.receivers.MemoryBuffer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PreserveOnRefresh;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@PreserveOnRefresh
@Route ( "upload" )
public class UploadView extends VerticalLayout
{
    // Constructor
    public UploadView ( )
    {
        this.add( new H1( "Upload" ) );
        MemoryBuffer buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
        Upload upload = new Upload( buffer );  // Connect our server-side `Receiver` implementation to the client-side `Upload` widget.
        upload.addFinishedListener(
                ( FinishedEvent finishedEvent ) -> {  // Event fired when user uses the `Upload` widget on the web page.

                    try (  // Autoclosable interface used in try-with-resources syntax.
                           InputStream inputStream = buffer.getInputStream() ;
                    )
                    {
                        // Read the data arriving in the buffer via the `InputStream` to produce a `String` object.
                        String s = IOUtils.toString( inputStream , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
                        this.add( new Paragraph( s ) );
                        System.out.println( "s = " + s );
                    }
                    catch ( IOException e )
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );
        this.add( upload );  // Make the `Upload` instance named `upload` appear on our Vaadin-produced web page.
    }
}
```

---

**Caveat:** The examples above are bare-bones minimal, as you asked. We have not done any error-handling nor react to the user canceling an upload mid-stream.

---

You may learn more by reading the [source code of the `Upload` component’s demo page](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-upload-flow/blob/master/vaadin-upload-flow-demo/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/upload/demo/UploadView.java) provided by the Vaadin Ltd company.

And read this detailed post about how *Upload* works in Vaadin Flow, [*Uploads and downloads, inputs and outputs*](https://vaadin.com/blog/uploads-and-downloads-inputs-and-outputs) by Matti Tahvonen.